# How can I install EGOPhotoViewer in my own app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

I try to install EgoPhotoViewer in my app, but when I run it in the simulator I got this error:

```
2012-01-02 09:02:07.450 EGO[1457:15203] Unknown class RootViewController_iPhone in Interface Builder file.
```

It runs, but my table view is empty. How can I solve it?

Comment: I downloaded the source from [github](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer) and run that. No crash. Please try again. Or give some specific info about changes you have made.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you may have copied xibs into your project from the EGO sample and didn't update the classes to point to the ones that exist in your project.